# Why am I not able to increase consumption from a Eventhub while using Kafka SDK? No matter how large the consumer configurations I provide, it is same

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, azure-eventhub

**Target**: To consume large amounts of data(20M records/Hr) from Azure Event hub topic using a custom Java application which uses Kafka-SDK and insert this data into Snowflake tables using JDBC connector.

**Environment**:
Event hub namespace: Premium tier, 4 PU
Custom java application running on : Azure App service (Isolated v2 I3V2, Instance count 3)
Kafka SDK version: 3.3.1

Note: Target is to consume 20M events/hour (Throughput will be 60GB/hr), There are 500M events waiting in Event hub to be consumed which are equally distributed on 10 partitions.
Each Event/Record size : 12KB to 150 KB

fetch max bytes = 90000000, fetch min bytes  = 50000000, fetch max wait ms = 10000, request timeout ms = 240000, heartbeat interval ms = 3000,  session timeout ms = 180000, max partition fetch bytes = 900000000, receive buffer bytes = 80000000

**Test results:**
if we set the batch size to 5000 with 1 thread, we are consuming batches ranging 2500 to 3000 records.
if we set the batch size to 5000 with 2 threads, we are consuming batches ranging 1200 to 1800 records.
if we set the batch size to 5000 with 10 threads, we are consuming batches ranging 200 to 300 records.

We are receiving records in batches ranging from 80 to 500/batch from all 10 partitions when running 10 threads in parallel.

**There is no throttling on Server side or Eventhub side. Observed CPU and Memory utilization under 20%.
**There are no errors logged.

From the above observations, no matter what we try to increase the total messages consumed, it always stay the same.

We have tried lot of different consumer configurations to bring the batch size to 1000 but we cannot increase the overall consumption speed.

**Note**: We have used Eventhub SDK in place of Kafka SDK with same setup and can see lot higher consumptions, but it is limited only when using kafka SDK.

Comment: Maybe contact Azure support. Sounds like there is a throttle theyre applying

Comment: How long is it taking to process the events ? while pooling, every poll call will load a set of records that were prefetched and are on memory, if the processing is taking long then the reduction in troughput will be observed.
Also, why are you limiting it to just 10 partitions ? you mght want to consider doubling that and then adding more instances

Comment: Can you clarify whether your Kafka consumers are cross region or not? Just want to see how much of network latency you should consider in your investigation.

Comment: I am in contact with Azure support and there was no progress.

For each poll call it takes around 200 ms to 4000 ms. But to see if the inserting to Snowflake causing any back pressure, we have removed the insert logic and ran our consumer just with consume logic where it will only pull events from eventhub, even then we saw the same limitation on batch size and we cannot pull more than 3000 events per batch with one thread. If we increase the thread count to 2, the batch size falls to 1500 even though we are requesting 3000 or above events per batch.